# Product of two hypergeometric functions

Tags: calculus, special-functions, hypergeometric-function

For $\Re a, \Re b, \Re c, \Re a', \Re b', \Re c'>0$,  I would calculate the following product
$$ {}_2 F_1(a, b; c; x^{-1}) \times \, {}_2 F_1(a', b'; c'; 1-\frac{x}{y}) $$ 
For all $y>x>1$.
Is there a formula that allows me to calculate the above product

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

This product of two Gaussian hypergeometric functions can be expressed by a sum over generalized hypergeometric functions ${}_{4}F_{3}$ according to formula 4.3.(14) on page 187 in "Higher Transcendental Functions, Vol. 1" by A. Erdelyi (Ed.). I reproduce it here for your convenience. (I've slightly changed the notation of the original.)
$$
{}_{2}F_{1}(a,b;c;p z) \ {}_{2}F_{1}(a',b';c';q z)= \\ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\ \frac{(a)_{n} (b)_{n} (pz)^{n}}{n!\ (c)_{n}}\ {}_4F_{3}(a',b',1-c-n,-n;c',1-a-n,1-b-n;\frac{q}{p}),
$$ where $(a)_{n}$ etc denotes the Pochhammer symbol. Note that for negative integer $a$ (and euivalently $b$ and per symmetry also for negative integer $a'$ and/or $b'$) the sum terminates. By setting $z=1$ and substituting $p$ and $q$ you get the solution that you are looking for.

Comment: What about the product of a 2F1 and a 3F2?

Comment: The formula I posted is a special cae of this formula: http://functions.wolfram.com/07.31.16.0001.01

Comment: Thanks very much, Johannes. I'll try to apply it to the problem I just posted https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2792124/simplify-re-express-if-possible-the-product-of-2f1-and-3f2-hypergeometric-func (also see my other related posting (without the added parameter k)  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/279867/perform-an-integration-involving-the-product-of-two-hypergeometric-functions   . I've now incorporated the product in question in a later version (yet to be posted) of https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.10680

Comment: Johannes, I don't think it is algebraically possible, in the particular case, in my indicated posting https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2792124/simplify-re-express-if-possible-the-product-of-2f1-and-3f2-hypergeometric-func to have a z, such that $c z= t^2$ and $d z=1-\frac{1}{t^2}$--so, I don't think I can make use of the Wolfram formula.

Comment: Maybe I miss the point, but isn't it possible to choose $z=1$ and $c=t^2$, $d=1-\frac{1}{t^2}$ ?

Comment: Thanks, Johannes! I'm pursuing your suggestion in the context of that https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2792124/simplify-re-express-if-possible-the-product-of-2f1-and-3f2-hypergeometric-func problem.